# Detecting dots from the camera in realtime using CIImage

Tags: swift, core-graphics

I'm writing an app in the latest Swift and I'd like to use Core Graphics to do image analysis on the camera's buffer.

I have the outputted pixelbuffer from each camera frame but am having trouble figuring out how to analyze this image on the GPU.

I'd like to be able to loop through the pixels on the GPU and calculate the center point of a specifically colored blob. As far as I can tell, CIImageDetector can only detect faces, rectangles, etc.

I've watched a video on CIImage and its capabilities already, so I understand kernels but not how to save data from the kernel, just modify existing data.

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: CI kernel code is a subset of OpenGL's GLSL. You don't "save" data from it. Like any CI filter, a kernel yields a CIImage as output. Sure, you can "save that - convert it to a UIImage and save it in a few ways... but that is like anything in iOS, use Swift or Objective-C.

Comment: I think this works best as a separate comment... if you want some good code on how to use CoreImage with the camera, here's a good link: http://flexmonkey.blogspot.com/2015/12/cartooneyes-compositing-cartoon-eyes.html. This post is just over a year old, so it's written in Swift 2. In it he uses CIDetector and replaces eyes with cartoon eyes. Last June/July he also posted on what changes are needed to use CI in Swift 3. Also, check out his "Filterpedia" iPad app repository for other custom kernels he wrote.

Comment: Thanks @dfd. I have watched his videos and read about the filterpedia app  but I am more interested in fast image analysis, not changing the image in any way.

Comment: Two more things that might help. First, not immediate, but announced today: CoreML. If you have the time to learn the "Apple way" of doing things, it may be worth it. I think it's a major announcement for WWDC 2017. Second, something requiring some learning also, but may be of help *today* - https://pjreddie.com/darknet/yolo/ - object detection. Honestly? Both look promising long term to me for a few apps.

Comment: @dfd, thanks for the resources! This stuff looks fantastic. What I'm looking to do is loop through the pixels in the image and average the locations of all pixels in range of a certain color tolerance. How would you go about this? Passing a CGImage to a c file? Could it be set up so that it runs on the GPU? I have a swift version running to analyze every one second and even that makes the device heat up...